# Exterior derivative of forms derived from a metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. From $g$ and a fixed vector field $V$ we can derive the following two differential forms:

- A $1$- form $\alpha(X) = g(V,X)$, i.e. $\alpha = \iota_Vg$.
- A $2$-form $\beta(X,Y) = g(V,[X,Y]) = g(V,\mathcal{L}_XY)$.

Notice that we obviously have $\beta(X,Y) = \alpha([X,Y]).$

Is there a nice expression for the exterior derivative $d\alpha$ and $d\beta$ of these forms? In particular, when are they zero?

I can get expressions in local coordinates, but they are kinda ugly and I cannot relate them to other known quantities.

Comment: The first is just the usual musical isomorphism $TM \to T^\ast M$ defined by the Riemannian metric $g$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism). The second looks familiar, but I can't place it for the life of me.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić I know, that's how I obtained it :) However I really need to understand its exterior derivative, and damn but I don't seem to be able to find anything nice...

Comment: O gosh, I'm stupid. I didn't notice you were looking for the exterior derivatives...

Answer (score 7):

A literal back-of-the envelope calculation leads me to $$d\alpha(X,Y)=g(\nabla_XV,Y)-g(\nabla_YV,X).$$ Does that help?

**EDIT**: Here is what I presume, 2 1/2 years later, was on the back of the envelope (with a few extra words).

Since $\nabla$ is $g$-compatible, we have $\nabla g = 0$, and so 
$$X(g(V,Y)) = \nabla_X(g(V,Y)) = g(\nabla_X V,Y) + g(X,\nabla_X Y).$$
Also, since $\nabla$ is torsion-free, we have $\nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X = [X,Y]$, so $g(V,[X,Y]) = g(V,\nabla_X Y)-g(V,\nabla_Y X)$.

Using the standard formula for the derivative of a $1$-form, we have
\begin{align*} 
d\alpha(X,Y) &= X(g(V,Y)) - Y(g(V,X))- g(V,[X,Y]) \\
&= g(\nabla_X V,Y) + g(V,\nabla_X Y) - g(\nabla_V, X) - g(V,\nabla_Y X) - \big(g(V,\nabla_X Y)-g(V,\nabla_Y X)\big)\\
&= g(\nabla_X V,Y) - g(\nabla_Y V,X),
\end{align*}
as required.

Comment: Nope, not really. Thanks for the effort anyway :)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to contribute a superior answer?

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: @TedShifrin Is it possible if you can provide the calculation here?

Comment: @Cookie. I've edited.